# I don't know how to dual-boot Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lubuntu, lvm

Quite simply, I don't know what I'm doing and I've come to the screen where it has the options: Erase Disk and Install Lubuntu, Encrypt, Use LVM or Something else.

I want to keep my windows 7, and I'm not sure whether to use LVM (Logical Volume Management) or 'Something else'(Custom Partitioning).

So, how do I dual-boot Windows 7 and Lubuntu?

Comment: Select `Something Else` and make a screenshot then upload it here.

Answer (score 0):

Partition your drive. Just know that Lubuntu won't recognize Windows drives.

Like user2548592 said, it may just be a better idea to install Ubuntu and get Lxde Desktop using `apt-get`.

This can be accomplished by running `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step "how to" for installing Ubuntu along side Windows.

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/installation

Comment: No help, Ubuntu doesn't install like Lubuntu.